# How to write a dynamic string replacement in git bash?

Tags: linux, git, bash, perl, sed

This is on Windows 10 using the Linuxy environment provided with Git Bash.

I have this line in my target source file:

```
'version' => 'v1.1.023',
```

I have this function in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
function tag() {
    ....
    tagname="$1"
    cmd="s:v[0-9]\\.[0-9]\\.[0-9]+:$tagname:g;"
    perl -p -i -e "$cmd" config/app.php
    ...
}
```

When I run the command:

```
$ tag v.1.1.024
```

The string is not replaced, therefore the version is not updated in my code. I tried a very similar script with sed instead of perl. The file isn't getting changed. I tried the same perl replacement syntax on CentOS and it worked. Note that the double-backslash appears to be required in order for the command to work on the next line when it's run in perl. That is to say, the variable string representation of the command has a double backslash so that it becomes a literal "." in the replacement.

Any ideas?

Comment: Re "*Note that the double-backslash appears to be required*", Shouldn't be. `printf '%s\n%s\n' "\." "\\."` shows that `"\."` and `"\\."` are functionally identical.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-i` doesn't work on Windows builds of `perl`.

```
>perl -i -pe1 foo
Can't do inplace edit without backup.
```

That feature uses anonymous files, which aren't supported by Windows. That said, you're not using a Windows build of `perl` but a cygwin build or similar. It could be that your unix emulation environment emulates anonymous files, so that might not be the the problem.

But if it is the problem, replacing `-i` with `-i.bak` will solve it. (Feel free to follow up with `rm config/app.php.bak`.)

---

By the way, you are generating Perl code, which is fragile. (Tag names containing `:`, `\`, `$` or `@` will cause the code to fail.) I recommend one of the following instead:

```
TAGNAME="$tagname" perl -i -pe's:v[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]+:$ENV{TAGNAME}:g' config/app.php
```

or

```
perl -i -pe'
   BEGIN { $tagname = shift(@ARGV); }
   s:v[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]+:$tagname:g;
' "$tagname" config/app.php
```

Comment: The OP is using a `perl` built with MinGW gcc: `C:\> "\Program Files\git\usr\bin\perl.exe" -v`: `This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for x86_64-msys-thread-multi`

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, Why are you telling me that? So I can test `-i` with it? I don't see how that helps me achieve that. Why didn't you do it?

Comment: I tried both, neither work for me. A .bak file is generated even though the target file is unchanged, I am using rm on the next line.

Comment: Re "A .bak file is generated even though the target file is unchanged", That means the pattern doesn't match.

Comment: Oh ok, I found the problem! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I ended up with TAGNAME="$tagname" perl -i -pe's:v[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]+:$ENV{TAGNAME}:g' config/app.php and then on the next line rm config/app.php.bak

Answer (score -1):

Hi @phpguru I would follow the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

**[Using sed](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq6.html) and avoiding perl**

> 6.3. When should I use sed?
>
> When you need a small, fast program to modify words, lines, or blocks
>   of lines in a textfile.

```
function tag() {
    tagname="$1"
    sed -i -e "s:v[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\+:$tagname:g" test.php
}
```

**Output in my environment:**

```
m.ortiz.montealegre@CPX-XYR3G1DTHBU MINGW64 ~
$ cat .bash_profile
function tag() {

    tagname="$1"
    sed -i -e "s:v[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\+:$tagname:g" test.php
}

m.ortiz.montealegre@CPX-XYR3G1DTHBU MINGW64 ~
$ cat test.php
'version' => 'v1.1.023,

m.ortiz.montealegre@CPX-XYR3G1DTHBU MINGW64 ~
$ tag v1.1.024

m.ortiz.montealegre@CPX-XYR3G1DTHBU MINGW64 ~
$ cat test.php
'version' => 'v1.1.024,
```

Comment: Your code suffers from an injection bug. Using `sed` correctly would be extremely complicated. KISS dictates you should avoid `sed`.

Comment: Even if you're ok with the injection bug, `sed` is no simpler that `perl` here. It's literally the exact same program except for the extra `\ ` before the `+` needed by `sed`.

Comment: Why would you use Perl which you already said is fragile? Sed has been around for many years and is the perfect tool to modify strings or lines of code http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq6.html

Comment: @ikegami using sed may be complex but not in this case.

Comment: I didn't say Perl is fragile; I said generating Perl code in a shell script is fragile. Generating sed code in a shell script like you did is equally fragile. In fact, your `sed` code-building suffers from exactly the same injection bug as the OP's Perl code building. Fix your injection bug if you think it's not complex; I think you'll find the Perl solution to be much simpler.

Comment: Tested on my environment - it doesn't work. No clue why. It's driving me nuts.